# Multiline string inside a chart value

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a helm chart. Inside the deployment folder I have a configmap template that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  app-properties: |
    {{ .Values.app.appProperties }}
```

My default values have this:

```
app:
  appProperties: |
    line1
```

That code appears to work, but I need more lines in app.appProperties and the moment I add more lines there like this:

```
app:
  appProperties: |
    line1
    line2
    line3
```

I get:

```
upgrade.go:142: [debug] preparing upgrade for myhelm
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on helm/templates/cms.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':'
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':'
YAML parse error on helm/templates/cms.yml
```

The templated definition I was expecting should be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  app-properties: |
    line1
    line2
    line3
```

What's the right way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason here is mostly because of the incorrect indentation which you can verify by running `helm template` with `--debug` flag. You could either use only `nindent 4` with your values as that seems to be the correct indentation level or also use [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) if the multiline string has some templates inside which you want to move in the config map.

```yaml
{{- /*
ConfigMap template 
*/ -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  app-properties:
    {{- .Values.app.appProperties | nindent 4 }}
---
## Values File  
app:
  appProperties: |
    line1
    line2
    line3
```

Result

```bash
➜  $ helm template ./         
---
# Source: my-local-functions/templates/multi-line-string.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  app-properties:
    line1
    line2
    line3
```

- Example with `tpl` function

```yaml
{{- /*
In the templates directory somefile.yaml
*/ -}}

multiLineString:
  {{- tpl .Values.multiLine . | nindent 2 }}

---

## Values Files

extraFruits: banana
multiLine: |
  I am a line
  {{ .Values.extraFruits }}
```

**Result:**

```bash
➜  $ helm template ./         
---
# Source: my-local-functions/templates/somefile.yaml
multiLineString:
  I am a line
  banana
```

Hope this helps.